# Struct Allocation in C Causing Memory Overwrite (I Think)

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc

I thought I understood this stuff, but I'm stumped here.

Given a struct declared as:

```
typedef struct _Thing {
  uint32_t type;
  struct _Thing *children;
  unsigned long childCount;
  char *description;

  union {
    uint32_t thirtyTwoBitValue;
    char *nameValue;
  } data;

} Thing;
```

I have a method that re allocates an array to accommodate adding a new Thing object. It looks like this:

```
void AddTopLevelThing(Thing *thing)
{
  Thing *oldThings = things;
  things = malloc(sizeof(Thing) * thingCount +1);

  // Add any existing things to the new array
  for (int i = 0; i < thingCount; ++i) {
    things[i] = oldThings[i];
  }

  // Add the newest thing to the new array
  things[thingCount] = *thing;

  // Increment the thing count
  thingCount++;
}
```

Note: things and thingCount are globals. Don't freak. ;-) Oh, and I also realize this is leaking. One problem at a time...

In order to create my Thing objects, I've created an initializer function. It looks like this:

```
Thing* CreateThingWithDescription(char *description)
{
  Thing *thing = malloc(sizeof(Thing));
  if (thing == NULL) {
    printf("Bad thing!, Bad!\n");
    return NULL;
  }

  // Initialize everything in the structure to 0
  memset(thing, 0, sizeof(Thing));

  thing->children = NULL;
  thing->description = strdup(description);

  return thing;
}
```

To complicate things (no pun intended), a Thing object has an array of children that gets reallocated (grown) when new objects are added to it. It looks like this:

```
void AddChildThingToThing(Thing *parent, Thing *child)
{
  Thing *oldChildren = parent->children;
  parent->children = malloc(sizeof(Thing) * parent->childCount + 1);
  if (parent->children == NULL) {
    printf("Couldn't allocate space for thing children.\n");
    parent->children = oldChildren;
    return;
  }

  // Add any existing child things to the new array
  for (int i = 0; i < parent->childCount; ++i) {
    parent->children[i] = oldChildren[i];
  }

  // Add the newest child thing to the new array
  parent->children[parent->childCount] = *child;  

  // Increment the child count
  parent->childCount = parent->childCount + 1;
}
```

Anyhow, I'm having a tough time figuring out why when I'm finished creating my structures and adding child structures that they are often zeroed out even though I validated their creation (in the debugger) when they were created. When the code in my main finishes running, I should have a tree structure, but instead it's just a mangled mess of values that I don't recognize or understand--which is why I believe things are getting overwritten.

Anyhow, I'm hoping I'm just overlooking something simple.

Here is my main if you want to see how I build my object hierarchy:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  things = NULL;
  thingCount = 0;

  Thing *thing = CreateThingWithDescription("This is thing 1");
  SetThingName(thing, "Willy Johnson");
  AddTopLevelThing(thing);
  Thing *child = CreateThingWithDescription("This is child thing 1");
  SetThingName(child, "Willy's Son");
  AddChildThingToThing(thing, child);
  child = CreateThingWithDescription("This is child thing 2");
  SetThingName(child, "Willy's Daughter");
  AddChildThingToThing(thing, child);

  thing = CreateThingWithDescription("This is thing 2");
  SetThingValue(thing, 700);
  AddTopLevelThing(thing);
  child = CreateThingWithDescription("This is child thing 3");
  SetThingValue(child, 1024);
  AddChildThingToThing(thing, child);

  for (int i = 0; i < thingCount; ++i) {
    PrintThing(&things[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note: this is just a demo project to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Identifiers starting with two underscores, or with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter, are reserved to the implementation; you should not define them in your own code (see `_Thing`). In fact, there's no particular reason not to use the same identifier for a struct tag and typedef; you can just write `typedef struct Thing { ... } Thing;` -- or, my own preference, omit the typedef and refer to the type by its proper name, `struct Thing`.

Comment: Nice Keith. So what's the philosophy there? Is it just for greater readability that you'd remove the typedef and just always declare `struct Thing` instead?

Comment: IMHO `struct Thing` already has a perfectly good name; little is gained by giving it another one. On the other hand, plenty of smart people disagree with me on this point, and think that it's worthwhile to have a name that's a single identifier. But even then, using distinct identifiers for the tag and the typedef is generally unnecessary. Or at least use a consistent convention (`foo_t` and `struct foo_s`, or whatever.) (Note that C++ cuts this particular Gordian knot by letting you define a type `struct Thing` and then refer to it as `Thing` without the need for a typedef.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to allocate one struct more, not one byte more in your `AddTopLevelThing` function:

```
things = malloc(sizeof(Thing) * (thingCount+1));
```

Also, you do not free the old memory block after reallocating.
And it's better to use `realloc` ('realloc' cares for copying old data and freeing old memory; it also can sometimes to perform reallocation 'in place' which is much more efficient):

```
void AddTopLevelThing(Thing *thing) {
    thingCount++;
    things = realloc(things, sizeof(Thing) * thingCount);
    things[thingCount-1] = *thing;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, same problem here: `malloc(sizeof(Thing) * parent->childCount + 1)`.

Comment: Also for the record, when doing this type of array expansion, the most efficient approach is to double the size of the array rather than adding one. You store `maxThings` in addition to `thingCount` and resize using `maxThings *= 2; realloc(things, sizeof(Thing) * maxThings); things[++thingCount] = *thing;`

Comment: @Chris good advice. I'd also add a switch to linear growth after some reasonable `maxThings` value, e.g. `if (maxThings < 4096) maxThings *= 2; else maxThings += 4096; realloc(...);`.

Comment: When I had implemented realloc (which I did first) it seemed like it wasn't copying everything over. Character strings would be empty after the realloc so I tried this other approach instead. Apparently the problem there was the same problem I am having here. Your answer was what I was looking for--something simple/stupid that I am missing. Thanks!